# Email Address special characters confusion

Tags: php, email-validation

I was playing around with `filter_var` to validate emails:

```
$email = "test@test.com"; 

if( filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){

    echo "{Valid Email";

}else{

    echo "Invalid Email";

}
```

That returns `Valid Email`.

But when I tried special characters like `. $ # * ? & ! ^ ~ / ' - _ @ % {} | = +` at the local part, Like :

```
$email = "te?st@test.com";
$email = "te/st@test.com";
$email = "te'st@test.com";
$email = "te}st@test.com";
$email = "te|st@test.com";
$email = "te=st@test.com";
```

That would return `Valid Email` too.

It's not accepting characters like `<> [] ,`.

But if I use `$`:

```
$email = "te$st@test.com";
```

That would return `Valid Email`, But also `NOTICE Undefined variable: st`

So should I use it to validate email addresses, Before inserting them to the DB?

Or I should use a custom Regular Expression?

Comment: The official RFC for emails is quite complex, lengthy, and incredibly inclusive of many weird things. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples for other valid emails. [In short, do not attempt this with regex because it's already been done and you probably don't know what you are doing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1903368/2191572) In your example `te$st@test.com` is interpolated as `te@test.com` because `$st` is undefined so a null (empty) is used in its place and you get a warning.

Answer (score 5):

When using double quoted strings, the `$` character is seen as the beginning of a variable name. So `$st`looks like a variable and PHP tries to interpolate it. This is easily resolved by using single quotes which does not interpolate variables in strings.

```
$email = 'te$st@test.com';
```

See the [PHP documentation for strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to learn more about this as it is an important part of PHP development.

Comment: You are right, But what if I'm checking the `$_POST['email']`, Would I face that issue too?

Comment: No, because PHP would be looking at the literal value of that variable like it was in some quotes and would not try to interpolate variables within it